# How do I get this diagram showing hydrogen bonds on LateX?

Tags: chemfig

[image]

I have managed to get this diagram but without showing the hydrogen bonds, so I was wondering if it is possible to add in the red hydrogen bonds shown in the picture.This is what I did to get the diagram without the bonds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 \chemfig{O(-[4]H)(-[6]H)}  & \chemfig{H - O - H} & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[6]H)} & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[6]H)} & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[6]H)}   \\ 
 \hline
  \chemfig{H - O - H} & \chemfig{O(-[6]H)(-[2]H)}  & \chemfig{H - O - H} & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[6]H)} & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[6]H)} \\ 
  \hline
 \chemfig{O(-[2]H)(-[4]H)} &  \chemfig{O(-[4]H)(-[6]H)}  &   \chemfig{O(-[2]H)(-[4]H)} & \chemfig{H - O - H}  & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[6]H)} \\
 \hline
  \chemfig{O(-[2]H)(-[4]H)} & \chemfig{H - O - H} & \chemfig{O(-[6]H)(-[2]H)} & \chemfig{O(-[2]H)(-[4]H)} & \chemfig{H - O - H} \\ 
  \hline
  \chemfig{O(-[2]H)(-[4]H)} & \chemfig{O(-[2]H)(-[4]H)} & \chemfig{H - O - H} & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[2]H)} & \chemfig{O(-[0]H)(-[2]H)} \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't see an obvious pattern in the bonds, so I guess you'd need to add them one at the time. In the example below I added a couple

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 4pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 1pt, outer sep = 3pt,
  help grid/.style={blue!30},
  bond/.style={thick, black},
  hbond/.style={thick, red, decorate, decoration = {snake, amplitude = 1pt, segment length = 5pt}}]

  % Atoms
  \foreach \y in {1, 3, ..., 9} {
    \foreach \x in {1, 3, ..., 11} {
      \node (Hodd\x-\y) at (\x, \y){$H$};
    }
    \foreach \x in {2, 4, ..., 10} {
      \node (O\x-\y) at (\x, \y){$O$};
    }
  }

  \foreach \y in {2, 4, ..., 8} {
    \foreach \x in {2, 4, ..., 10} {
      \node (Heven\x-\y) at (\x, \y){$H$};
    }
  }

  % Frame + grid
  \foreach \x in {0.5, ..., 11.5}  \draw[help grid] (\x, 0.5) -- (\x, 9.5);
  \foreach \y in {0.5, ..., 9.5}  \draw[help grid] (0.5, \y) -- (11.5, \y);

  % bonds
  \draw[bond] (Hodd1-9) -- (O2-9);
  \draw[hbond] (O2-9) -- (Hodd3-9);
  % ...
  \draw[bond] (Hodd1-1) -- (O2-1);
  \draw[hbond] (O2-1) -- (Hodd3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]